# Which tense do I use for an on-going event that has a connection to the past

Tags: tenses

For example, please consider the following sentence:

"The site was disapproved for not having enough unique content. The site has mostly links and banner ads that would negatively impact the user experience."

The second sentence seems awkward to me and I am not sure if it should be the way it is written or follow the tense in the first sentence.

Kevin

Comment: Both sentences seem awkward to me. To translate into English: I didn't like your website cos, er, too many links, er yeah, too many links.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on ELL.

Answer (score 1):

The site was disapproved for lack of unique content, overuse of links and banner ads, all deemed counteractive to the user's experience.

Answer (score 0):

You can say:

The site, which has mostly links and banner ads that would negatively impact the user experience,  was disapproved for not having enough unique content.